# Improving cross-validation throughput in TensorFlow, Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, profiling, cross-validation

I am working on CNN models which are intended to predict a protein's structure from its amino acid sequence.  I am implementing my CNN's in Keras.  The Keras API is the one that comes bundled with TensorFlow 1.4.0, so obviously TensorFlow is my backend.  I have installed the GPU version of TensorFlow, and I have verified that the GPU is being used.  My GPU is somewhat older, an NVidia GTX 760.

When I perform 3X cross-validation to help select architectures and hyperparameters, I have 50K examples in my training folds and 25K samples in my validation folds.  These are decently large data sets, however they're small in comparison to the RAM available in my computer (16 GB) or on my GPU (2 GB).  Fully unpacked and expressed as float32 values, with redundancy introduced because of sliding windows, all the folds taken together, input plus target values, occupies 316 MB.  I have pre-calculated my folds, and saved files of each fold to disk.  When I experiment with architectures and hyperparameters, the same folds are being used in every trial.

I started with networks containing a single hidden layer to see what I could achieve, and then switched to two hidden layers.  I used a fixed batch size of 64 for all of my early experiments.  Training proceeded quickly enough that I didn't concern myself with speed.  Performing a 3X cross-validation for a given architecture typically took about 12 minutes.

But in the last experiment that I did with two-layer networks, I decided to start investigating the effect of batch size.  I learned that smaller batch sizes gave me better results, up to a point.  Batch sizes of 8 were the smallest ones that I could count on not to crash.  My loss values will occasionally flip to NaN with batch sizes of 4, and they will frequently flip to NaN with batch sizes of 1 or 2.  After that occurs, the network becomes untrainable.  I am aware of the possibility of gradient instability.  I think I was getting some.

So why not just use batch sizes of 8 and keep going?  The problem is speed.  Using two hidden layers, batches of eight took me approximately 35 minutes to cross-validate.  Batches of 64, as I mentioned above, took one third that much time.  My first experiments with three hidden layers have taken 45 to 65 minutes per trial.  And I want to investigate potentially hundreds of architectures and hyperparameters, using still deeper networks.  With small batches, I can see that the batch-by-batch progress bar in Keras progresses more slowly.  I can see much longer pauses when an epoch ends.

Yes, I can upgrade my GPU to a 10 series.  I think that will only double my throughput at most?  Yes, I can rent GPU time in the cloud.  Eventually I might do that.  But if my software is inefficient, I definitely don't want to set it loose in the cloud to burn my money.

It is my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong) that when the GPU is used in a normal TF / Keras work flow, each individual batch is sent separately from the GPU to the CPU.  If I am training 50 networks in a 3X cross-validation scheme, this would mean that I'm sending the same data to my GPU 150 times.  As I mentioned earlier, all my data occupies at most 316 MB, about 15% of the RAM available on the GPU.  Can I devise a workflow which sends this 316 MB to the GPU **once**, and if so, will that have a useful impact on my throughput?  Intuitively, it feels like it should.

Are there other bottlenecks I should be thinking about?  Is there a way to profile TF or Keras operations?

Thanks for any advice you may have!

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I know that you're more concerned about throughput from Keras and your hardware, but there are a few things I'd like to mention here:

1. **smaller batch sizes gave me better results**

Given you case, where you have not so huge data, assuming you're running the training for fixed number of epochs (say 5), training with lesser batch size is naturally expected to give you a slightly better result as it would mean a higher number of back-prop steps overall compared to that of a higher batch-size. If you're training for a fixed number of training steps instead, I don't know why this is happening.

2. **loss values will occasionally flip to NaN with batch sizes of 4**

Again, I'm assuming you're using batch-normalization here, with CNNs. While using BN, it's never actually recommended to use a smaller batch-size like 2 or 4 (or even 8). And probably, one of the reasons why you can be facing NaN with smaller batch-size is if you have low-variance in the current batch and if you take the epsilon value too small, you might have very small values that can lead to numerical instability going forward. But more generally, this might be a case of gradient instability like you mentioned. Consider using gradient clipping to see if it helps.

3. **GPU Workflow**

Here, I assume that you have only 1 GPU. And unfortunately, you can't parallelise using single-GPU. To clarify, you shouldn't be concerned about the size of your data for GPU RAM. In most of the single-GPU cases, the current batch stays on the CPU and GPU would only take up the operations. Rather, you should be concerned about the size of parameters that GPU would be computing. Since for 1-layer experiment and 3-layers experiment your operations differ a lot, I don't think it's possible as you can't place multiple ops on same device simultaneously. The best case for you here would be to use a larger batch-size (not too large - as this would reduce the number of back-prop steps in case of training for fixed-epochs), so that you'd cover more data in a single-go.

Just a tip for hyper-paramter tuning, you can consider using [Highway-CNNs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06228). These are inspired from gating mechanism of LSTMs where you specify a large number of hidden layers and the network figures out itself on how to control the information flow among the layers. So in short, this would practically eliminate your efforts of tuning the depth of network, and allowing you tune other hyper-params like learning rate or filter-sizes etc.

I hope at least some of this is relevant and helpful to you ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, End-2-End.

Comment: (Continued...) Clarifications are in order: please check this post of mine on Cross-Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351890/neural-network-training-going-backward-to-go-forward) which describes my stopping process.  I am seeking a minimum validation error before stopping.  I haven't used any batch normalization so far because 1) each of the possible amino acids in the input is encoded by a 20-dimensional one-hot vector, 2) I'm only at 2-3 layers deep, and 3) my activation function is Swish.  I will investigate Highway-CNN's as you suggest.

Comment: 1. Got your point on BN. 
2. Saw your post on CV. Its an interesting question that you pose, on when to stop the training. And unfortunately, there's no golden rule to stop the training process. At least not yet. Contrary to playground-example you've mentioned, I've also seen many cases where validation loss would go up and (a) never come back and (b) comes back down but not to a further lower point. So it really depends on the problem you're working on and the shape of the loss function.

Comment: I don't know if you've seen this paper [Early Stopping | But When?](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/prechelt/Biblio/stop_tricks1997.pdf). According to this paper, you can wait for your validation loss to come back down to a lower point, but the computational costs would in general out do the difference in the validation loss and its significance on test set. So their basic principle is to set a threshold on validation loss and stop it as soon as the val_loss crosses it while going up. Do have a look and see if it helps.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, any specific reason you've gone with Swish activation function? I've been looking around for a while on better use-case on Swish function. I've tried various use cases comparing a lot of activation functions and in almost all of them Leaky-Relu seemed to outperform all of them. [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/fFltV43.png) the results of one of the experiments. Lemme know if you've tried other functions before or if there's any reason for choosing Swish.

Comment: "I don't know if you've seen this paper Early Stopping | But When?"  I started to read it a few months back.  Your post prompted me to go back and read it in more detail.  It looks like the stopping criteria as defined in that paper are more complex than the conditions defined in the Keras early stopping callback.  So are my early stopping conditions, but mine may also not be sophisticated enough.  The paper seems to confirm my suspicion that if training loss is still dropping significantly, it might be worth letting validation loss rise for a while.

Comment: "If you don't mind my asking, any specific reason you've gone with Swish activation function?"  I wanted to use an activation function from the "self-normalizing" family.  I tried both ReLU and SELU before settling on Swish.  With my specific problem, I got significantly more rapid convergence using Swish.  Intuitively, I've always been bothered by the fact that the derivative of ReLU is discontinuous.  SELU is also discontinuous at a point, and possibly concave at the discontinuity too, depending on the value of a hyperparameter.